# como inserto nuevas filas en jtable con checkbox sin que me seleccione la ultima fila seleccionada con el checkbox

Tags: java, checkbox, jtable

al seleccionar un checkbox de mi tabla funciona bien incluso al desseleccionarlo, el problema viene luego de seleccionar un checkbox y eliminar todas las filas del mismo color , cuando las vuelvo a agregar se queda marcado la posicion del ultimo checkbox seleccionado, no importa que tabla muestre , lo muestro, aca selecciono este checkbox y todo bien (imagen 1) :[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Elimino todas las filas al desmarcar la tabla y todo bien (imagen 2): [image: imagen 2]
Luego cuando vuelvo a marcar la tabla que se elimino del jtable vuelve a quedar marcado el ultimo checkbox seleccionado como se muestra aca (imagen 3): [image: imagen 3]
El codigo que utilizo para llenar el jtable es este :

```
 public static void setListar(String busca,String tabla) {
    try {
        DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) pnlHome.tabla_general.getModel();
   
        inicio ini=new inicio();
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+ini.server()+":1521:XE";
        // Establecemos los valores de cadena de conexión, usuario y contraseña
        cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "GOYA","GoyaAdmin01");
        //Para ejecutar la consulta
        s = cn.createStatement();
        //Ejecutamos la consulta y los datos lo almacenamos en un ResultSet
        rs = s.executeQuery("select * from "+tabla);
        String sql = "";
        if (busca.equals("")) {
            sql = "select * from "+tabla;
        } else {
            sql = "SELECT * FROM "+tabla+" WHERE ("
                    + "id_goya LIKE'" + busca + "%' OR "
                    + "no_cxto LIKE'" + busca + "%' OR "
                    + "no_de_expediente LIKE'" + busca + "%' OR "
                    + "UPPER(tipo_de_cxto) LIKE UPPER('" + busca + "%') OR "
                    + "UPPER(area) LIKE UPPER('" + busca + "%') OR "
                    + "UPPER(unidad) LIKE UPPER('" + busca + "%') OR "
                    + "UPPER(resp_area) LIKE UPPER('" + busca + "%') OR "
                    + "UPPER(resp_unidad) LIKE UPPER('" + busca + "%') OR "
                    + "UPPER(estado_expediente) LIKE UPPER('" + busca + "%')"
                    + ")";
        }
        
        
        
        Object datos[] = new Object[12];
        try {
            s = cn.createStatement();
           rs = s.executeQuery(sql);
          while (rs.next()) {
                datos[0] = rs.getString(1);
                datos[1] = rs.getString(2);
            datos[2] = rs.getString(3);
            datos[3] = rs.getString(4);
            datos[4] = rs.getString(5);
            datos[5] = rs.getString(9);
            datos[6] = rs.getString(10);
            datos[7] = rs.getString(11);
            datos[8] = rs.getString(12);
            datos[9] = rs.getString(17);
            datos[10] = tabla;
            datos[11] = false;
            modelo.addRow(datos);
            }
          pnlHome.tabla_general.setModel(modelo);
          pnlHome.tabla_general.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new EstiloTablaRenderer());
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(pnlHome.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            ErrorAlert error = new ErrorAlert(new JFrame(), true);
            error.msj1.setText(ex.toString());
            error.msj2.setText("Por favor contacte con soporte técnico");
            error.msj3.setText("");
            error.preferredSize();
            error.pack();
            error.setVisible(true);
             
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(pnlHome.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(pnlHome.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
}
```

Para agregar los checkbox en el jtable utilizo las clases CellEditor y CellRender , las muestro :
CellEditor :

```
public class Clase_CellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor implements TableCellRenderer{
private final JComponent component = new JCheckBox();    
private boolean value = false; // valor de la celda

/** Constructor de clase */
public Clase_CellEditor() {
    super( new JCheckBox() );
}

/** retorna valor de celda
 * @return  */
@Override
public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    return ((JCheckBox)component).isSelected();        
}

/** Segun el valor de la celda selecciona/deseleciona el JCheckBox
 * @param table
 * @param value
 * @param isSelected
 * @param row
 * @param column
 * @return  */
@Override
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
    
    
    
    // tuneado del jchecbox
    ( (JCheckBox) component).setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/contrato/uncheck_tabla.png"))); // NOI18N
   ( (JCheckBox) component).setIconTextGap(12);
   ( (JCheckBox) component).setSelectedIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/contrato/check_tabla.png"))); // NOI18N
    
    //Color de fondo en modo edicion
    ( (JCheckBox) component).setBackground( new Color(69,87,252) );
    // colocar el checbox en el centro de la celda
    ( (JCheckBox) component).setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
    //obtiene valor de celda y coloca en el JCheckBox
    boolean b = ((Boolean) value).booleanValue();
    ( (JCheckBox) component).setSelected( b );
    return ( (JCheckBox) component);     
}

/** cuando termina la manipulacion de la celda
 * @return  */
@Override
public boolean stopCellEditing() {        
    value = ((Boolean)getCellEditorValue()) ;
    ((JCheckBox)component).setSelected( value );
    
    return super.stopCellEditing();
}

/** retorna componente
 * @return  */
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
     if (value == null)
        return null;         
     return ( (JCheckBox) component );
}
```

}

CellRender:

```
public class Clase_CellRender extends JCheckBox implements TableCellRenderer {

public final JComponent component = new JCheckBox();

/**
 * Constructor de clase
 */
public Clase_CellRender() {
    setOpaque(true);
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    // tuneado del jchecbox
    ((JCheckBox) component).setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/contrato/uncheck_tabla.png"))); // NOI18N
    ((JCheckBox) component).setIconTextGap(12);
    ((JCheckBox) component).setSelectedIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/contrato/check_tabla.png"))); // NOI18N
    if (table.getValueAt(row, 10).equals("gestion_produccion")) {
        component.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(184, 204, 228));
        component.setForeground(Color.black);
        component.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 14));
    }
    if (table.getValueAt(row, 10).equals("sistema_base")) {
        component.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(242, 220, 219));
        component.setForeground(Color.black);
        component.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 14));
    }
    if (table.getValueAt(row, 10).equals("gestion_aplicaciones")) {
        component.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(252, 213, 180));
        component.setForeground(Color.black);
        component.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 14));
    }
    if (table.getValueAt(row, 10).equals("sistema_comunicaciones")) {
        component.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(217, 229, 189));
        component.setForeground(Color.black);
        component.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 14));
    }
    // para seleccionar toda la fila al seleccionar el checkbox
    table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
    table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
    //obtiene valor boolean y coloca valor en el JCheckBox
    boolean b = ((Boolean) value);
    ((JCheckBox) component).setSelected(b);
    // colocar el checkbox en el centro de la celda
    ((JCheckBox) component).setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
    return ((JCheckBox) component);
}
```

}

Alguien tiene alguna respuesta para mi o mejor aun , alguna solucion a mi problema ?

Comment: no me muestra ningun error , solo marca la posición que coincide con el ultimo checkbox marcado, si hay ninguna fila para ese checkbox no muestra nada , ni error ni nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solucionado y optimizado el código !!!!!!!!!!
Solo segui los pasos de este sencillisimo video encontrado en youtube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_LywyuL8y3Y (creditos al creador) y elimine unos codigos y una clase completa , aca muestro como queda :
clase CellRender:

```
public Clase_CellRender() {
    setOpaque(true);
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    // tuneado del jchecbox
    ((JCheckBox) component).setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/contrato/uncheck_tabla.png"))); // NOI18N
    ((JCheckBox) component).setIconTextGap(12);
    ((JCheckBox) component).setSelectedIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/contrato/check_tabla.png"))); // NOI18N
    
    //Color de fondo en modo edicion
    ( (JCheckBox) component).setBackground( new Color(69,87,252) );
    
    if (table.getValueAt(row, 10).equals("gestion_produccion")) {
        component.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(184, 204, 228));
        component.setForeground(Color.black);
        component.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 14));
    }
    if (table.getValueAt(row, 10).equals("sistema_base")) {
        component.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(242, 220, 219));
        component.setForeground(Color.black);
        component.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 14));
    }
    if (table.getValueAt(row, 10).equals("gestion_aplicaciones")) {
        component.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(252, 213, 180));
        component.setForeground(Color.black);
        component.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 14));
    }
    if (table.getValueAt(row, 10).equals("sistema_comunicaciones")) {
        component.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(217, 229, 189));
        component.setForeground(Color.black);
        component.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 14));
    }
    
    //obtiene valor boolean y coloca valor en el JCheckBox
    boolean b = ((Boolean) value);
    ((JCheckBox) component).setSelected(b);
    // colocar el checkbox en el centro de la celda
    ((JCheckBox) component).setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
    return ((JCheckBox) component);
}
```

}

Clase CellEditor eliminada, y en el initComponents() de la clase que tiene la tabla principal este codigo para que cargue el render :

```
tabla_general.getColumnModel().getColumn(11).setCellRenderer(new Clase_CellRender() );
```

y asi se soluciono todo despues de mas de 5h :)